# JSP and JavaScript with form

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I have a form in a Registeration.jsp page:

> form name="users" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCorrect()"
>   action="Registeration.jsp">

The Script checkCorrect is written at the start of the page, returns true or false based on information submitted to the form (using getElementById if it matters) and the script definitely works (worked on html page without jsp before)

after the form I have this:

> <% if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")){...}

And I need that the jsp part will work ONLY if and after the form is successfully submitted, but somehow the javascript script is not called and don't work and the form is always submitted.

What am I doing wrong?

edits:
there's no redirection in my page, the javascript check function, the form, and the JSP part that procces the form after submitting it are at the same page.
the jsp part is used to send the data from the form to a database.
the function:

> function checkCorrect(){
>   var fullname=document.getElementById("fullname").value;
>   ...
>   if (response.length==0)
>        {
>          return true;
>        }
>        else
>        {
>          alert ("These problems are found in your form:\n\n"+response);
>          return false;
>        }
>   }

then come the `body` and the form and then
the jsp part:

> <%
>
> if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")){
>
> String fullname=request.getParameter("fullname");
>   and go on.. } % >

Solution:
check the JavaScript part really good people it doesn't have compiler so even a tiny problem there can screw up the entire project.

Comment: As I understand, ``registeration.jsp`` and ``Registeration.jsp`` are same page? Also, why you should do ``onSubmit=checkCorrect`` to call it on submit, not on load.

Comment: maybe you could post the javascript you are using. Have you tested with firebug or other tool to see if checkCorrect is called?

Comment: @AdamJurczyk
yes they are the same page, and i need to call it on submit because the function validates the info entered in form on submit of the form and if there's a problem with data entered i need it to not submit the form.

Comment: @roel
i don't know how to use firebug and those tools maybe can you refer me to a good guide? :)

also - i'm using eclipse on ubuntu 10.10 with apache tomcat 6 and mysql server

Comment: JSP is a HTML code generator. JavaScript is part of HTML. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. This should enlighten the most starters.

Comment: @Kristal, can see the text entered by pasting this `document.getElementById("fullname").value` into the browser console?

Answer (score 3):

```
<% uname=""+request.getAttribute("username"); %>
```

This variable will get a value only when you load your page or refresh it.

I guess your page flow is as follows.

You have your first page with form, and onsubmit form will call javascript function as

```
<form name="users" method="post" onSubmit="returncheckCorrect()" action="Registeration.jsp">
```

then your javascript will check your answer like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function returncheckCorrect() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("userName")
    if (your condition) {
        alert("Redirecting");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Not Redirecting");
        return false;
    }
}
// return false; // lol, see why indentation is useful ?
</script>
```

then (if (your condition == true)) your java script will redirect to a second page where you want to get the value in a scriptlet like

```
<% uname=""+request.getAttribute("username"); %>
```

Make sure your code is in this manner.

Following is the code which I tried as you said, its working

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkme() {
        var x = document.getElementById('textfield');
        if (x.value == 'sarin') {
            alert("success");
        } else {
            alert("failed");
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="chkme();"
        action="">
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" /> <input
            type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" /> <input
            type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <%
        if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            String textfield = request.getParameter("textfield");
            String textfield2 = request.getParameter("textfield2");
    %>
    <%=textfield%>
    <br />
    <%=textfield2%>
    <%
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The page is too large, i can't copy it to here =\ it's pretty much like you wrote but the script is in the `<head>` section between `<script language="text/JavaScript"></script>`  
then this:  

`<%

  if(request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
  {   
        
      String fullname=request.getParameter("fullname");
      String email=request.getParameter("email");
      
      String username=request.getParameter("username");
      String password=request.getParameter("password");`
comes right after the form

Comment: also, i'm not redirecting to anywhere.. the javascript check function, the form, and the JSP part that procces the form after submitting it and send the data from the form to a mysql database, are all on the same page. any idea how to improve it will be great :)

Comment: @Kristal, While explaining your question its better to update your question and put comments about what all things you modified. then it will be helpful for others also...

Comment: Your logic seems to have some problems.
After the execution of java script, I am affraid that your scriptlet will not get values, because scriptlet gets value only when page loads..

Comment: Its better to put database submission and other things in next page. May be you could achieve these things in same page if you are integrating ajax to your page. But I am not much experienced in ajax to tell the correct methods for that.

Comment: Ok, i will redirect to another page, but now i use the jsp to get the values from the form like this: `request.getParameter("fullname");`  if the jsp part will be in another page how can i get the values from the form?

Comment: I tried the code as you said.. its working

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>


<% if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")) { 
 String fullname=request.getParameter("textfield"); 
 String email=request.getParameter("textfield2"); 


%>
<%=fullname%><%=email%>
<%}%>

Comment: whoa yours really works but mine still doesn't. I will try to modify mine based on all of your comments, I believe it will work.. thanks guys for the help :)

Comment: Previous answer was having mistakes

Comment: I actually had a really really dumb mistake in the javascript part but now it works just fine :) admin can flag it as solved thanks guys

Comment: @kristal,post your corrected answer and mark it as accepted.. It will be helpful for others..